# DSolve does not solve a nonlinear differential equation

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following nonlinear differential equation. Mathematica does not give any solution.

```
uap = uat*Exp[-I*w*(t - X*Cos[theta]/c)]
pde = 
  -I*w*Ze[X, t] + (ua*Cos[theta] + uap*Cos[theta])* D[Ze[X, t], X] + 
    Sl*D[Ze[X, t], X]^2 - uap*Sin[theta]
DSolve[pde == 0, Ze[X, t], {X, t}]
```

The output is the same as input statement `DSolve` with `pde` substituted from the above variables, with a warning

> Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information. >>

Can anyone please suggest what is wrong with the input command. I am new to mathematica and I followed instructions in the documentation. I was able to reproduce the examples given in documentation, but this particular problem doesn't work.

Comment: Try DSolve (capital S)

Comment: @ Ulrich Thank you for pointing out the typo. I used DSolve[ ] in my mathematica notebook. Mathematica doesn't give any solution but a warning `Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information. >>` and the output is the same as the input as I had mentioned earlier.

Comment: You try to solve a nonlinear pde,which doesn't contain derivatives D[Ze,t]. The output (same as input) -message shows that MMA doesn't find a solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you solve your pde for `D[Ze[X,t],X]` Mathematica is able to solve the explicit pde:

```
tmp = Solve[pde == 0, D[Ze[X, t], X]][[1]];
pdenew = tmp /. Rule -> Equal;
Simplify[ DSolve[pdenew, Ze[X, t], {X, t}][[1]] ]
(*{Ze[X, t] ->E^((I w X Sec[theta])/ua) (-((2 I c E^((
      I w (-2 c t ua Cos[theta] + 
         X (-2 c + ua + ua Cos[2 theta])) Sec[theta])/(2 c ua))
       uat (1 + (E^((I w (-c t + X Cos[theta]))/c) uat)/ua)^(-((
       c Sec[theta]^2)/ua))
       Hypergeometric2F1[((-2 c + ua + ua Cos[2 theta]) Sec[
         theta]^2)/(2 ua), 
       1 - (c Sec[theta]^2)/
        ua, ((-c + ua + ua Cos[2 theta]) Sec[theta]^2)/
       ua, -((E^((I w (-c t + X Cos[theta]))/c) uat)/ua)] Sin[
       theta])/(w (-2 c + ua + ua Cos[2 theta]))) + (E^(I t w)
      ua + E^((I w X Cos[theta])/c) uat)^(-((c Sec[theta]^2)/ua))
   C[1][t])}*)
```

Comment: @ Ulrich Could you please tell me which version of mathematica you use?

Comment: @Sreenath: v 11.0.1 Windows 7